# VBA function to skip cells that would create duplicate (errors) worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to replicate a template and fill out certain cells within that template using information from a table.

The issue I'm running into is that if I run the macro, and there are worksheets generated, and then add rows to the table with updated information, I get an error because some of the names are already in use.

Is there any way to set it up so that if I add rows to the table and then run the macro, that it would create only tabs for the added rows and skip over the duplicate rows that were previously generated?

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, nm As String, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("TenantList")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In ws.Range("b5:b" & ws.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        nm = c.Value
        If Len(nm) <= 31 Then 'check name no too long
            If Not SheetExists(nm, wb) Then
                wb.Worksheets("TenantTemplate").Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = nm
                c.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:="'" & nm & "'!B5", TextToDisplay:=nm
            wscount = wscount + 1
                If Len(nm) > 0 Then  ' ignore blanks
                  On Error Resume Next
                End If
                Set ws = Nothing
            End If 'no existing sheet with this name
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Worksheets created: " & wscount
End Sub

'Is there a worksheet named `SheetName` in workbook `wb`?
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook)
    Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function
```

I expected this to generate new worksheets based on the input of the table, but I have not been able to figure out how to skip duplicates, which generate errors and doesn't allow me to run again without deleting the created tabs first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test to see if a sheet already exists with the name in `c`:

```vb
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, nm As String, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("TenantList")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In ws.Range("b5:b" & ws.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        nm = c.Value
        If Len(nm) > 0 And Len(nm) <= 31 Then 'check have a name, and name not too long
            If Not SheetExists(nm, wb) Then
                wb.Worksheets("TenantTemplate").Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = nm
                c.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:="'" & nm & "'!B5", TextToDisplay:=nm
            End If 'no existing sheet with this name
        Else
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed 'flag too long
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Is there a worksheet named `SheetName` in workbook `wb`?
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook)
    Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Appreciate your comment. This worked. I have an updated ask on this, however. Some of the worksheets that are being attempted at being created have names that are too long and are generating an error. Do you know what the best way to code this so that it skips rows from the range that are generating errors and continues generating the remaining worksheets?

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Getting a debug error and it's highlighting the "wb.sheets (wb.Sheets.count) .Name = nm" line, creating no worksheets, and highlighting the cells in the range prior to the error.

Comment: Sorry fixed above `If Len(nm) <= 31 Then`

Comment: Fantastic. That worked beautifully. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Added a function to generate a message box and have attempted adding a line of code to skip blanks but it's causing a debug error. Reason I need to skip blanks is because there is a row in the range table for "totals" and was causing an error when the macro was run.

Comment: `If Len(nm) >0 And Len(nm) <= 31 Then 'check have a name, and name not too long`